# Excel - get column reference (i.e. F:F) from user select cell Reference (i.e. F5)

Tags: excel, lambda

I'm trying to create a LAMBDA function here where user have to select a cell (i.e. cell F5), and then, from the given user input I need it to become column reference (i.e. F:F). Which then I can use this column reference in my INDEX or MATCH formula

How do I go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that I can use INDIRECT function.

i.e. INDIRECT(colLetter &":"& colLetter)